# Deleting a record from the table from a file

Tags: php, arrays

I downloaded the data from the file and saved it to the table, then I try to search the array and write "Match found" if it is in the table, if I do not write "Match not found"

my file voucher.txt

```
ub65rf
98huf4
YbyR42
```

My code PHP

```
$array = [];
$array = file('voucher.txt');

$find = '98huf4';


if (in_array($find, $array))
  {
  echo "Match found";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Match not found";
  }
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `file()` includes the newlines in the strings, so they don't match your `$find` string. There's a flag to remove them.

```
$array = file('voucher.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```